# Stored procedure mapping with table (entity) in EF Core (.Net 6) with a database-first approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Previously I was working on EF 6 (with a database-first approach) with ASP.NET MVC 4.5. There, you can map stored procedures with entities to perform some operations as required (on Insert/Update...) using the `.edmx` model.

Now, I want to map the same stored procedures with the same tables (entities) but using EF Core (.Net 6.0.400).

I am able to perform entity related operations (like Insert/Update) but I still want to run a logic written in a stored procedure during the insert/update of an entity.

Could you please suggest how can I map any stored procedure with an entity?

Any ideas/suggestions/path would be appreciated.

Comment: For now: you **cannot** do this in EF Core - I know, I wish you could - but it's just plain not there. There's something in the works for EF Core v7 which should be out by Nov 2022 - but right now , that feature just plain doesn't exist in EF Core.

Comment: You have to wait for EF Core 7.0 - [Map CUD operations to stored procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/plan#map-cud-operations-to-stored-procedures). Until then (somewhere Mid of Nov this year), you just have no options with EF Core.

Comment: @marc_s , Thanks for the quick answer. It didn't occur to me to check out the upcoming releases.

Comment: @IvanStoev, Thanks for your quick answer and for the link too.

Comment: Actually it is already implemented and you can use it at least in 7.0.0-rc1